# Best way to perform a statistical analysis in MySQL

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I have a table with 320 columns. Each column may contain one of five letters (a,b,c,d,e) - a multiple choice test. Now I'd like to perform a statistical analysis having in mind that if nine of 10 persons answering a question with 'b', 'b' will be likely correct.

How can this be done in the most efficient way? I have thought about a view with order by and limits but is this efficient for 320 columns?

Comment: [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: How many rows are in your table? You might be better off copying the whole thing into a spreadsheet application such as Excel, and perform your analysis there. Spreadsheet applications are better suited at performing identical operations on many columns, if the number of records is not too large (less than 50.000 or so).

Comment: I don't really see a reason for a downvote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to to the math for each column. sql is made to calculate on rows.

to get count of answers for each question:

```
select * from
(select a as answer union select b union select c union select d union select e) answers

left join 
(select answer_to_q1 as answer, count(*) as q1 from table group by 1) q1 on q1.answer=answers.answer

left join 
(select answer_to_q2 as answer, count(*) as q2 from table group by 1) q2 on q2.answer=answers.answer

... repeat for all columns
```

to get the answer with highest count, where q1, q2 etc are the columns that have your answers to q1 q2..

```
select 1 as question, q1 from table group by q1 order by count(*) desc limit 1
union all
select 2, q2 from table group by q1 order by count(*) desc  limit 1
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is far from optimum.

If you normalize your data structure you'll find it is a lot easier. Make a table called answer:

```
create table answer (
    questionnaire_id int, -- an id number for which questionnaire this is 
    question_id int,      -- the id number of the question
    answer enum('a','b','c','d','e') -- the value of the answer 
);
```

Then you can look at the distribution of each question with queries like this:

```
select question_id, answer,count(*)
from answer
group by question_id, answer; -- just one example of how to look at the answers
```